# Laravel mail sent but still throws exception

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I am sending an email in laravel like this:

```
Mail::send('email.email_view', [] , function($message) {

    $message->to('email@gmail.com', 'Receiver Name')
            ->subject('TTTTTT');
});
```

The view "email.email_view" only contains this:

```
test this
```

What happens is that the email gets sent and I receive it in the inbox, but still it throws this exception:

> local.ERROR: Connection to tcp://mail.myserver.net:2525 Timed Out
>   {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection
>   to tcp://mail.myserver.net:2525 Timed Out at
>   /home/public_html/test/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:473,
>   Swift_IoException(code: 0): Connection to tcp://mail.myserver.net:2525
>   Timed Out at
>   /home/public_html/test/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:166)
>   [stacktrace]

*If you need the (stacktrace) tell me where to put it online for you guys, I understand there are online tools for it?.*

Why does this happen? How to prevent sending emails if an exception is thrown through the process?

Comment: This problem started happening when the server was down and the support had to fix things and make it live again. So may be the problem has to do with what they did to fix it. But can't put my hand on anything!

Answer (score 1):

The error traceback shows that a timeout is happening before the socket finishes being read from.

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/v6.2.1/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php#L159

The default `15 seconds` to be enough time gap between reading of individual packets from the socket connection opened to the email server.

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/v6.2.1/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php#L279

I suggest to *investigate your network connection*, or look into why the email server takes long to send back packets.

As a last resort, you can increase the timeout by resolving `Swift_Transport` instance from the service container and calling the `setTimeout` method on it. Do this before sending out mail.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.4.0/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php#L103

```php
app('swift.transport')->setTimeout(60);
```

Comment: Now, Our support has fixed the two servers that were causing the timeout error and I can't test it anymore. It's sending emails now so fast with no exceptions. But I will have to regenerate the error myself to report the bug. For now I won't use swiftmailer anymore. I will look for another trusted email client and advise others to do the same.