# Could email be sent but still throws an exception?

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

So I am want to send an email and record in the database that it was sent successfully, here is what I do:

- First, try sending an email to the user containing the product information
- Second, check if the email was sent successfully. If yes, then record in the database that it was sent successfully.

But if sending the email failed (an exception was thrown) I want to catch that exception and return an error message.

**My question is:**
Is there a case that the email gets sent but still throws an exception?

So by that the code returns error thinking that the email wasn't sent .. but it was actually sent and the exception was throw later after that.

```
    // pseudo code      
    try{
        $is_sent = send_email();
        if($is_sent){
            $db->email_was_sent();
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return 'Email was not sent. An exception';
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$is_sent` ? What is the value of `$e` ?

Comment: @YazanWYusuf it is either true or false. but the `send_email()` could throw an exception, so I need to handle it by the `try/catch` statement. `$e` is the exception thrown by `send_mail()` if there was one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a case that the email gets sent but still throws an exception?

It depends.

If email is sent for a single recipient, any 3 of these situation could result:

- email is delivered to recipient
- email failed to be delivered to recipient
- an exception was raised

For this case, it would be undocumented behaviour of the SwiftMailer email client
to have an email sent but still throw an exception.

If email is sent to several recipients, any 3 of these situation could result:

- email is delivered to all recipients
- email failed to be delivered to one or more recipient(s)
- an exception was raised

For this other case, email could be delivered to some recipients and still raise an exception.

https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html#using-the-send-method

`AbstractSmtpTransport::send()` shows that email may fail to be sent for one or more of the recipients.
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/v6.2.1/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php#L178

Comment: With a single recipient, sending the email but still throwing an exception is a bug, right?

Comment: With a single recipient, when there is an exception one can expect that the mail was never delivered. Is the email being sent in your application and yet throwing an exception? If so, you could log the exact error that is raised and file an issue if there isn't one for it already here https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues

Comment: Yes it is sent in one my servers but throwing an exception and I couldn't know if the email was sent or not because of the exception. I wanted to generate the error myself in another server then I would raise an issue. Please have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58228883/4365678 . I added some details.